# How to show Union is convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $\{x_1,x_2,.......,x_{n-1}\}$ be linearly independent set in $\mathbb R ^n$. Then  complement of subspace generated by these elements in $\mathbb R ^n $ has two connected components. Let  $u$ belongs to first component and $v$ belongs to second component.

Let $A=convex hull\{u,x_1,......,x_n-1\}$ and $B=convex hull\{v,x_1,......,x_n-1\}$.

As $\{u,v,x_1,......,x_n-1\}$ is linearly dependent set there exist constant s.t.
$au+bw+c_1x_1+......+c_{n-1}x_{n-1}=0$.

Prove that if constants $c_1,......c_{n-1}$ are non-negative then $A\cup B$ is convex.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking here.

Comment: @copper.hat I have edited the question.